# Unity get Type of the service where the dependecy gets injected

Tags: c#, ninject, unity-container

Is it possible to get, in Unity, the Type of the service where the dependecy gets injected?

In `Ninject` you can do it like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod((context) =>
{
    ILogger logger = HttpContextLoggerFactory.GetInstance();

    // Eg: MyApplication.PeopleRepository
    string memberType = context?.Request?.Target?.Member?.DeclaringType?.FullName;

    return new LoggerMemberTypeDecorator(logger, memberType);
});
```

How can the same thing be implemented in `Unity`?

Here is what i have, but i do not have access to any `context`

```
container.RegisterType<ILogger>(new InjectionFactory(u =>
{
    ILogger logger = HttpContextLoggerFactory.GetInstance();

    // how to get it?
    string memberType = "";

    return new LoggerMemberTypeDecorator(logger, memberType);
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846342/how-to-inject-log4net-ilog-implementations-using-unity-2-0

Comment: The respective answer It's not aplicable

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your Service (whose type then gets reported to the injected dependency's constructor) with a special `InjectionConstructor`.

Shamelessly copying my own answer (see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056082/how-to-get-the-type-of-the-object-that-is-being-injected-in-unity/43064453#43064453)):

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, Implementation>( new MyInjectionConstructor() );

internal class MyInjectionConstructor : InjectionMember
{
    public override void AddPolicies( Type serviceType, Type implementationType, string name, IPolicyList policies )
    {
        policies.Set<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>( new MyConstructorSelectorPolicy(), new NamedTypeBuildKey( implementationType, name ) );
    }
}

internal class MyConstructorSelectorPolicy : DefaultUnityConstructorSelectorPolicy
{
    protected override IDependencyResolverPolicy CreateResolver( ParameterInfo parameter )
    {
        if( parameter.ParameterType == typeof( ILogger ) )
        {
            return new LiteralValueDependencyResolverPolicy( new Logger( parameter.Member.DeclaringType ) );
        }
        return base.CreateResolver( parameter );
    }
}
```