# Using unity for logging

Tags: c#, logging, unity-container

I'm using UnityLog4NetExtension for logging in my C# application.

```
using log4net;
public class MyClass
{
private static readonly ILog LOG = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Log.Info("Starting application...")
}

}
```

Would I be able to inject and use ILog in this class?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284091/unity-get-type-of-the-service-where-the-dependecy-gets-injected